# Approval workflow tutorial using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, workflow-activity, tutorials

I am new in Sharepoint 2010 and up to this point I was working with Sharepoint designer 2010 but it limits my choices so I need to learn how to develop approval workflows in visual studio 2010. I do not want ready made solutions or codes, I need good tutorials to start with. Do you have any proposals of maybe a youtube video, a blog or a site?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good one: [SharePoint 2010: Create a Workflow Activity using Visual Studio 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13604.sharepoint-2010-create-a-workflow-activity-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx):

Try and google:

`developing custom workflow actions`

or

`developing custom workflow activities`

Here is a good general one for [SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163911.aspx)

Then add SharePoint 2010 to the end of the query, and you can find the ones for 2010.

Comment: Great!  Hit the upvote if it's useful :).